Regex that replace number lower than 100 by a string in sed script
I'm testing regular expressions in .sed script to replace a number < 100. I have to change numbers lower than 100 only in the fifth field of the CSV.
The CSV is separated by commas.
Example CSV:
datetime,car,brand,model,km,new
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,ford,f150,20,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,yamaha,r7,1560,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,renault,twingo,37,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,honda,cbr600rr,2000,no

and i have this script:
# Replace
s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)\(0\|[1-9][0-9]\{0,1\}\)\([^,]*\)/\1none\3/

answer in terminal must be:
datetime,car,brand,model,km,new
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,ford,f150,none,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,yamaha,r7,1560,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,renault,twingo,none,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,honda,cbr600rr,2000,no

I run the script with
sed -f script.sed ./sample.csv

and the answer is
datetime,car,brand,model,km,new
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,ford,f150,none,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,yamaha,r7,none60,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,renault,twingo,none,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,honda,cbr600rr,none00,no

it replace always the first to numbers, not only the fields that have number to 0-99.
EDIT: I cant use awk for that.
Could you help me?
Thank you very much.
Best regards.

The regexp needs to match the , after the number. Change \([^,]*\) to \(,[^,]*\)

Otherwise it matches the first 2 digits of a larger number, and the rest of the number goes into \3, so 1234 becomes 12none

sed -E -e 's/,[0-9]{1,2},/,none,/g' < in.csv but this relies on not having spaces surrounding the commas. It would be clearer to parse the CSV as CSV, and then work on the fields you want to change.

look the desired response, i only want to replace the numbers lower than 100 in the five group of the csv, named km

This would be much easier in awk. $5 < 100 { $5 = "none" }

i know but i have to learn first to do that with a sed script, i cant use awk since next month.

using addresses would help too /[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[1-9]?[0-9],[^,]*/ s/....

what are addresses?

Thank you to Barmar, i dont see his answer and there was in the first comment.

Too bad no awk yet for you: awk -F, '$5<100{$5="none"}{print}'

both awk above are wrong - Barmar's doesn't print lines that match, Léa Gris' doesn't set OFS. : awk '$5>=100 || $5="none"' FS=, OFS=, sample.csv

I solved this based on Barmar's comment. In the last group, I had to change \([^,]*\) to \(,[^,]*\).
The solution is:
# Replace
s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)\(0\|[1-9][0-9]\{0,1\}\)\([^,]*\)/\1none\3/


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/[^,]+/\n&\n/5;s/\n.{,2}\n/none/;s/\n//g' file 

Erect some newline scaffolding around the fifth field.
Use pattern matching to replace one or two digits only in the fifth field with none i.e. 100 or more have three or more digits.
Remove the scaffolding.

Technically this isn't changing the fifth field:
sed 's/,[0-9]\{,2\}\(,[^,]*\)$/,none\1/' sample.csv

sed -E 's/,[0-9]{,2}(,[^,]*)$/,none\1/' sample.csv

Aternatively:
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}\)[0-9]\{,2\},/\1none,/' sample.csv

sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){4})[0-9]{,2},/\1none,/' sample.csv


To also exclude numbers written like 000010, just prefix 0* to [0-9]
